# Org-mode: divide agenda by blocks of 20 items

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode, time-management

I want to implement [Autofocus system](http://www.markforster.net/autofocus-system/) in org-mode using agenda views. Autofocus is a time-management system, where you write tasks in a lined notebook with 25-35 lines on a page and you don't start working on the next page until you processed the current page.

By default agenda collects all todos and throws them in a buffer altogether. I want to break these todos by blocks of 20 tasks, for example, so i can process one batch of 20 tasks, then another batch, and so on.

How can i do it? Any solution from using org-mode built-in trick to some emacs lisp snippet is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this going the same way as the agenda usually goes, i.e. chronology, so I don't think there are meant-to-be ways to do that. What comes to my mind, though, is defining your batches with tags (`:` in the agenda to set tags, say on the first 20), then filtering by tags (`/ SPC` to filter on tags of the current line).

The first idea I had was basically the same with priorities : `S-<up>` in the agenda to set them, but then filtering by priority is described [here on the mailing list](http://osdir.com/ml/emacs-orgmode-gnu/2010-04/msg00311.html), but doesn't seem that easy.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, `org-agenda-max-todos` and `org-agenda-max-entries` might be what you are looking for.

Note: I have never used them. I came across these a while ago